# Countries mxd file?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, mxd

Anyone know where I can get a decent mxd file that has country boundaries.  Currently I'm using the world.mxd file that comes with ArcObjects; however, what I really am looking for is one that has all of the counties so I could click on a country and get it's boundaries in a List of Points so I could draw an outline around said country.

I'm looking for one that's free - obviously that might be a problem, but figured I'd throw it out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want the actual shapefile, not the mxd file. I have used this stand alone tool to export the boundaries of the shapefile for use in other programs (it allows you to export the coordinates in a csv file as well as various other file types)

[DNR Garmin App](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/tools/arcview/extensions/DNRGarmin/DNRGarmin.html) from the Minnesota Department of Natural Resources

If that isn't an option I imagine someone can give a code snippet of how you would extract this info in either VBA or Python (or whatever language). You could always check out the [Free Geography Tools](http://freegeographytools.com/) blog and it may have other programs that can do this for you.

Comment: Shape file was the answer.  So now I can click on the map, the IIdentifyObj tells me I clicked on the United States.

Comment: Just need to figure out how to get the list of points....anyone know how that works?

Comment: @PSU, the DNR link I pointed to has a stand alone tool that you can upload shapefiles to and extract the boundary vertices of that shapefile (even if it is a polygon shapefile). I just used the tool with a US State boundary file though and it took quite a while to upload, you may want to simplify the world country shapes before using that tool (depending on what you want to do with the vertices this may not be a bad idea anyway).

Comment: orginfo (http://gdal.org/ogrinfo.html) will also also print a full list of vertices for any shapefile.  Just omit -so (summary) and you're all set.  You can pipe it to a text file if you need.